# 'no release file' error when installing ubuntugis

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntugis

I'm trying to install ubuntugis-unstable on Ubuntu 20.04.1 but get an `no release file` error.

I've used:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Answer (score 1):

Following the instructions from the [website](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable/?field.series_filter=bionic), you should add

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu bionic main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable/ubuntu bionic main
```

to your sources list. A ppa behaves different from a repository.

Alternatively, on the command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
sudo apt-get update
```